# Swift Mailer error: Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I was trying out some PHP scripts to send a mail to my gmail account. I am using Swift Mailer library. Here is my PHP code.

```php
<?php
/// Swift Mailer Library
require_once 'swiftmailer-5.x/lib/swift_required.php';

// Mail Transport

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('ssl://smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    ->setUsername('myemail@gmail.com') // Your Gmail Username
    ->setPassword('my_password'); // Your Gmail Password

// Mailer
try {
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('New Mail')
    ->setFrom(array('myemail@gmail.com' => 'myemail')) // can be $_POST['email'] etc...
    ->setTo(array('myemail@gmail.com' => 'myemail')) // your email / multiple supported.
    ->setBody('Test Mail', 'text/html');

// Send the message
if ($mailer->send($message)) {
    echo 'Mail sent successfully.';
} else {
    echo 'I am sure, your configuration are not correct. :(';
}

} catch(Swift_TransportException $exception) {
    var_dump($exception);
}

?>
```

I have turned on Access for less secure apps in my Gmail account and the mail was sent once. But afterward its giving me this error.

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
```

I did some research but was not able to nail down on an exact reason for this error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Seems a little weird. When I updated the gmail settings to allow access for less secure apps it started working. Although when i hosted the website onto a free server and used the URL on my phone the mails weren't  going. Is there any settings that i need to do in order to send mails from my cellphone as well?